# Counting number of columns in text file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-columns

I have two text files composed of spaced-separated columns. These are excerpts of these two files:

FileA

```
 1 1742.420   -0.410  20.1530   0.4190   1.7080   0.5940
 2 1872.060    0.070  21.4710   0.2950   0.0670   0.3380
 3 1918.150    0.150  18.9220   0.0490   1.4240   0.1150
 4 1265.760    0.170  19.0850   0.0720   1.3330   0.1450
 5  308.880    0.220  20.5020   0.1570   0.0200   0.1720
 ....
```

FileB

```
 1 1198.367    6.465  15.684 0.015  3.119 0.140  1
 2 1451.023    6.722  17.896 0.031  0.171 0.041  1
 3 1032.364    6.788  18.895 0.074 -0.084 0.088  1
 4  984.509    7.342  19.938 0.171  0.043 0.322  1
 5 1068.536    7.369  19.182 0.091  0.486 0.143  1
 ....
```

As you can see FileA has 7 columns and FileB has 8. This is the code I use to count the columns:

```
import csv
file = 'filename'
reader = csv.reader(file)
num_cols = 0
for col in reader:
    num_cols = num_cols + 1
```

This little code correctly gives the number of columns for FileA (7) but not for FileB (also gives 7) What's going on and how can I fix it?

If I'm counting rows instead of columns then: 1- how can I count the columns? and 2- given that my actual files have several thousands of lines/rows, why am I getting these results (7)?

Comment: You are counting rows.

Comment: The actual text files have several thousands lines/rows, so if I'm counting rows that raises another set of questions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is correct.  You could say `for bunnies in reader` and you will still be looking at rows, not columns.  Just count the elements of the first row, as others have suggested.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
import csv

with open('filename') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    first_row = next(reader)
    num_cols = len(first_row)
```

Comment: No need to use `iter()` here; `csv.reader()` objects are iterable directly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I wasn't sure. I extrapolated from `next([1, 2, 3])` erroring. You're right though - `next(csv.reader(['a, b, c']))` works just fine

Comment: The code works great but could you explain a bit more what is it doing? I'm having trouble understanding the _with_ and the _next_ statements in particular.

Comment: @Gabriel: the `with` statement is the prefered way to work with files - it closes the file automatically when the scope is left. `next` takes an iterator, and returns the next (in this case, first) item from it. `next(my_iterator)` is equivalent to `list(my_iterator)[0]`

Comment: @Gabriel: except `list(it)` iterates over all values.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Yeah, I probably should have said "equal to". They can certainly have different side effects

Answer (score 2):

Read just the first line, use split to find all non-whitespace parts, count those:

```
with open("bla") as f:
    line = f.readline()
print(len(line.split()), "columns")
```

Answer (score 0):

just get the length of the first row!!

```
import csv
file = 'my_File.csv'
reader = csv.reader(open(file,'rb'),delimiter=" ")
num_cols = len(next(read))
```

Comment: I don't think [`csv.reader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) takes a filename. Also, this is not normal csv, so requires extra configuration to parse.

Comment: Also, python 3 deprecates/removes `i.next()` in favor of `next(i)`

Comment: I had no clue as to I use 2.7. And yes That was a typo, I forgot to add the `open`