# Count the number of sets of columns separated by strings in python

Tags: python, text

I am reading a .txt file in python. It contains five columns of numbers. I have tried to find the number of elements using

```
numcols = len(linesX[0])
```

Unfortunately, since python reads the .txt as a list of strings

```
f = open('XdataTXT.txt','r')
linesX=f.readlines()
```

The output is 81 instead of 5. I have tried to implement the solution offered in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448912/counting-number-of-columns-in-text-file-with-python), but since they are dealing with a .csv instead of a .txt I cannot replicate the results. Can someone help me?

In the attached image you can see how my original data looks.[image: xt]

Comment: Please don’t share information as images unless absolutely necessary, which isn’t the case here. Can you share a [mcve]? It isn’t clear to me what the issue is. Are you just asking how to read this whitespace-delimited data? If so, there are plenty of resources on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `csv` library does not depend on the filename suffix. It's the data in the file that it deals with. Therefore you can definitely still use the `csv` library for this.

```
import csv

with open('XdataTXT.txt','r') as f:
    numcols = len(next(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')))
```

Or if you don't want to use the library just use `str.split`:

```
with open('XdataTXT.txt','r') as f:
    numcols = len(f.readline().split())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am afraid that numcols is 1 instead of 5 if I write with open('XdataTXT.txt','r') as f:
    numcols = len(next(csv.reader(f)))
f.close()

Comment: You need to set the delimiter to a space as the dafault is a comma. See my edit.